# Why does the Fastify CLI process forcefully end?

Tags: node.js, fastify

I have a [Fastify](https://www.fastify.io/) web server that exposes a bunch of RESTful endpoints. I created my project using [fastify-cli](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cli) and I also use the CLI to run the server locally. I notice that whenever I rapidly call my APIs, I get the following error in my terminal:

[image]

You'll notice that I call the same API repeatedly. I don't get any errors in the first two or three calls but, when I call the same API a third or fourth time, the server process crashes and automatically restarts a few seconds later.

Since the logs are sparse, I can't seem to figure out what might cause this issue and I wonder if it is an issue with the CLI itself? Appreciate any help from other Fastify users.

Comment: How do you start it? I think that is the `watch` feature that reload when a file change

Answer (score 2):

It is a known bug with the watch feature [cli issue](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cli/issues/168)

not fixed yet.